# Select everything up until one of two characters in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, string, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a field that has the following data format:

```
"45 -Example1"
"22-Example2"
"10-Example3"
"5 -Example2"
```

I need the leading number, AKA select everything up until a space or the "-" character.  How can I do that?

---

Comment: Your google search string is `oracle string functions`.

Comment: Including the quotes or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this using `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(col, '[^ -]+', 1, 1)
```

Comment: Grazie mille, signore.

Comment: would this not give you the entire string after space or hypen if the number is missing before it?

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `substr` and `instr`.

```
select trim(substr(col,1,instr(col,'-')-1))
from tablename
```

A better option would be using `regexp_substr` so you get `null` if the leading number is missing before a space or hyphen.

```
select regexp_substr(col,'^(\d+)[ -]',1,1,null,1)
from tablename
```

Comment: . . It is either a space or a hyphen, not just a hyphen.  I understand the answer but not the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I would use regular substr and instr:

```
select substr(col, 2, least(instr(col, ' '), instr(col, '-')) - 2) from...
```

Substring starting at the second position (the second argument to `substr` is 2) because presumably you don't want to pick up the double-quote `"` (or is that NOT part of the string, you just used it for whatever reason?)

`least(....)` picks up the position of the first space or dash, whichever is first. The third argument to `substr` is the number of characters to be returned; so we subtract 2, for the leading `"` and the training `space` or `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Others may have beat me to it but test for the unexpected!  My version checks for the first occurrence of 1 or more numbers followed by a space or a dash.  Have a plan to deal with an unexpected or missing value found.

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
  2    select '45 -Example1' from dual union
  3    select '22-Example2'  from dual union
  4    select '10-Example3'  from dual union
  5    select '5 -Example2'  from dual union
  6    select ' -example5'   from dual union
  7    select '-example6'    from dual union
  8    select 'a-exampl7'    from dual union
  9    select 'Z -example8'  from dual
 10  )
 11  select nvl(regexp_substr(str, '(\d*?)( |-)', 1, 1, NULL, 1), ERROR') leading_nbr
 12  from tbl;

LEADING_NBR
------------
ERROR
ERROR
10
22
45
5
ERROR
ERROR

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```